# Euler #26, how to convert rational number to string with better precision?

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I want to get `1/7` with better precision, but it got truncated. How can I get better precision when I convert a rational number?

```
>>> str(1.0/7)[:50]
'0.142857142857'
```

Comment: I think perhaps he means problem 26?  http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=26

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has a built-in library for arbitrary-precision calculations: Decimal. For example:

```
>>>from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>>getcontext().prec = 50
>>>x = Decimal(1)/Decimal(7)
>>>x
Decimal('0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714')
>>>str(x)
'0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714'
```

Look at the [Python Decimal documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) for more details. You can change the precision to be as high as you need.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the decimal module. This is the easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

You could multiply the numerator by a large 10^N and stick with arbitrary-precision integers.

**EDIT**

i mean:

```
> def digits(a,b,n=50): return a*10**n/b
.
> digits(1,7)
14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714L
```

Python's integers are arbitrary precision. Python's floats are never arbitrary precision. (you'd have to use Decimal, as another answer has pointed out)

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl (because I can't write Python ;-):

```
use strict; use warnings;

use integer;

my $x = 1;
my $y = 7;

for (1 .. 50) {
    $x *= 10 if $x < $y;
    my $q = $x / $y;
    $x -= $q * $y;
    print $q;
}

print "\n";
```

```
14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714
```

As you can verify by hand, the digits repeat. Printing using `"%.50f"` will give you the *illusion* of more precision.

Comment: Indeed, all rational numbers eventually repeat.

Comment: This simple method actually works. I will convert it to Python and use it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sinan, I know the digits repeat, but to detect repeating patterns in other rational numbers (1/d where d < 1000), I need more precision.

Comment: @Keith Randall: What do you mean?

Comment: @grokus: I was pointing out that the output from using `%.50f` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

With [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/):

```
>>> import gmpy
>>> thefraction = gmpy.mpq(1, 7)
>>> hiprecfloat = gmpy.mpf(thefraction, 256)
>>> hiprecfloat.digits(10, 50, -10, 10)
'0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714'
>>>
```

You can't do it with normal floats -- they just don't have enough precision for 50 digits!  I imagine there's a way to do it (in 2.6 or better) with `fractions.Fraction`, but I'm not familiar with any way to format it otherwise than as `'1/7'` (not very useful in your case!-).